# RegExp capturing group in capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture the "1" and "2" in "http://test.com/1/2". Here is my regexp `/(?:\/([0-9]+))/g`.
The problem is that I only get `["/1", "/2"]`. According to http://regex101.com/r/uC2bW5 I have to get "1" and "1".

I'm running my RegExp in JS.

Comment: So how are you using it in JS? I suspect you're using `match` wrong...

Comment: Here, use this https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/5506663

Comment: Great function @elclanrs

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use a `while` loop over `RegExp.prototype.exec`:

   ```
   var regex = /(?:\/([0-9]+))/g,
       string = "http://test.com/1/2",
       matches = [];

   while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
       matches.push(match[1]);
   }
   ```
2. Use `replace` as suggested by [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs):

   ```
   var regex = /(?:\/([0-9]+))/g,
       string = "http://test.com/1/2",
       matches = [];

   string.replace(regex, function() {
       matches.push(arguments[1]);
   });
   ```

Comment: I was thinking that match will return all of the match group with out using while loops.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript your "match" has always an element with index `0`, that contains the WHOLE pattern match. So in your case, this index 0 is `/1` and `/2` for the second match.

If you want to get your DEFINED first Matchgroup (the one that does not include the `/`), you'll find it inside the Match-Array Entry with index `1`.

This index `0` cannot be removed and has nothing to do with the outer matching group you defined as `non-matching` by using `?:`

Imagine Javascript wrapps your whole regex into an additional set of brackets.

I.e. the String `Hello World` and the Regex `/Hell(o) World/` will result in :

```
[0 => Hello World, 1 => o]
```